# Using Serilog and Sentry during ASP.NET Core startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, sentry

I am trying to log errors thrown during app startup to sentry. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1.2, with Serilog and Sentry. If I use just sentry, it seems to work okay.

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSentry("dsn")
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

However, if I add Serilog, the app does not send any events during startup, although it keeps working if an exception is thrown from a controller action.

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog(
        (hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            loggerConfiguration
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.Sentry(s => {
                    s.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
                    s.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                }))
    .UseSentry("dsn")
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

I'm trying to log from both the `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods in the Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public ILogger<Startup> Logger { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Logger.LogError(new Exception("something went wrong while configuring services"), "ERROR");

        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Logger.LogError(new Exception("something went wrong while configuring app"), "ERROR");
    }
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the order of the initialization of each logger, but I don't undertand the startup process enough to come up with a solution or at least an explanation. Any idea why this happens and how could I fix it?

**Update**

It seems that explicity adding the DNS to the serilog configuration also fixes the issue, although this seems to be against the samples in the sentry repo.

```
.UseSerilog(
        (hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            loggerConfiguration
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.Sentry(s => {
                    s.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
                    s.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                    s.Dsn = new Dsn(dsn);
                }))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core logging infrastructure is built before the application request pipeline. For that reason, we can capture exceptions that happen during app start only via a Logging integration.

The reason that application initialization errors are captures when you use *only* [`Sentry.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.AspNetCore/) is that this package depends on [`Sentry.Extensions.Logging`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Extensions.Logging/).

When you do `UseSentry`, it internally hooks into the frameworks logging infrastructure.
Crashes in the `Startup` class happen before the app is actually built (the completion of `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` are required to boot the app) so only using the Logging integration we're able to capture errors at that point.

Once you add `Serilog` to your app, [the default logging backend gets replace by it](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/67). That means that the hooks to the logging infrastructure done by `Sentry.Extensions.Logging` no longer take effect now that `Serilog` has taken over.

For that reason you need to add the package `Sentry.Serilog` too. 
In this case, with both packages added, you're able to capture bootstrapping errors only if you initialize the SDK via the `Serilog` integration (as you did per your last comment). That's not done in the samples to avoid confusion (why do I need to provide my DSN twice?) but what happens under the hood is that the first initialization, done by Serilog is only really useful until the `Startup` process is finished. Once `Sentry.AspNetCore` is initialized, it'll close the first client created by the `Serilog` integration and flush all events and add a new client to the main scope. This makes sure things like request data are also added to the event.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But it it possible to limit Serilog integration to report to Sentry only in PROD endironment? Eg do not report dev errors. Right now I can archieve this with appsettings.Production.json, but this startup errors are required Dns to be set, which mean they will report even in Dev